# Magento 2 datetime picker

Tags: magento, magento2, datetimepicker

[datetimepicker ui component from Magento 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0nIS.png)

How do make a call to action the Selected Hour in PHP
I want the 9am have a minutes limit of 30min only and the rest have the completely 60 minutes.
I manage to restrict the dates and hour 9am to 2pm

Here's the code:

public function getSelectHour()
    {
        $image = $this->getBaseUrl() . 'pub/media/calendar/images/calendar.png'; //path to pub/media/

```
    $options = [
        'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        'timeFormat' => 'hh:mm a',
        'showsTime' => true,
         'showOn' => 'button',
         'buttonImage' => $image,
         'buttonImageOnly' => true,
         'buttonText' => 'Select Date and Time',
         'minDate' => 'new Date() + 2',
         'hourMin' => 9,
         'hourMax' => 14,
         'controlType' => 'select'
     ];
    return $options;
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULwSQ.png)

Comment: Please don't use screenshot to show your code, copy it directly in your question.

Comment: Thanks @MickaelB.Im new here. Here you go. How can I call the value of 9am in datetimepicker do you have idea?